# How to connect google compute engine backend(Node.js + websocket) and firbase web app(frontend-vue.js)?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, devops

Recently, I clone my github project to deploy backend and push my vue app on firbase with https.

I need to export port 3030 as my websocket port, so I use .env file to connect to my backend

```
VITE_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN= mapbox token 
VITE_APP_BACKEND_SERVICE_PROTOCOL=https
VITE_APP_BACKEND_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST= my backend IP address
VITE_APP_BACKEND_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=3030
```

and my backend .env file below

```
FRONTEND_URL= **here is my frontend domain name**
BACKEND_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=3030
RABBITMQ_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=127.0.0.1
RABBITMQ_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=5672
RABBITMQ_SERVICE_USER=xxxx
RABBITMQ_SERVICE_PASSWORD=xxxxx
MYSQL_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=3306
MYSQL_SERVICE_USER=root
MYSQL_SERVICE_PASSWORD=xxxx
JWT_TOKEN_SECRET= xxx
TLS_KEY = xxx(for https)
TLS_CERT= xxx(for https)
```

Now, I'm sure that rabbitmq and mysql is connected successfully.
But when I access to my frontend web page the console show that

```
Get https://xxxxx:3030/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OUE7nj3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

and

```
Get https://xxxxxx:3030/api/v1/user/me net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I don't know why I can't access the backend services from compute engine.
I'm the beginer in cloud services so I'm not familiar with the details of why this happend.

Could anybody answer my confuse on this problem?

BTW, I also try to push my frontend and backend both in the compute engine,
it can connect front and backend successfully in http but my website need to use position and camera lens so I need to use https in my web pages.